# Free all function keys ( F1-F12 ) for gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, key-mapping

I'm using `gnome-terminal` and I need to free all the F keys because I need to remap them to something else inside `vim`, how I can do that?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @don_crissti from F5 to F12 prints a tilde `~` under my Ubuntu, except F11 that goes fullscreen and F10 that opens the gnome-terminal menu. F1 opens the online help, from F2 to F4 are already free apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to modify the sources, no you can't. [The F1 is hard set](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/82a9a6581afc04aa6ba7f2451ce501edb19cd6e5/src/terminal-window.c#L2467) to help pages for most (if not all applications), F10 can be disabled but you will still get the `~` in the underlying shell. This is observable on the TTY, also.

Comment: not directed at you (not your fault), but "you can't" is *never* an acceptable answer for all algorithms in P.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure what you are trying to convey.

Comment: Oh, just expressing my annoyance (frustration?) at a too common phenomena of wanting to do something but it isn't possible for no good reason other than "we didn't do in a way that supports that".

Answer (score 1):

It is not hardcoded (though some of the programs you run inside the terminal *may* be).

Checking Ubuntu 13.04, its version of gnome-terminal is 3.61, which supports the dialog for modifying *keyboard shortcuts*:

- You reach that by going to the *Edit* menu, and selecting *"Keyboard Shortcuts..."*.
- In the dialog, you can modify any entry by clicking on it (on the right, where the column header says *Shortcut key*).
- After clicking, the text is temporarily replaced with *New accelerator*.
- **Type** the key that you would like that function to be reassigned to.
- Repeat this for all of the keys you want to modify.